How to fix lacquer mark from sanding, I cleaned, stripped, then cleaned this table top, when i started to sand this occured - any ideas?
Please help, see image for review - is it lacquer i sanded into the table.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Yes regrettably it does look like you sanded right through the veneer — if you Google "sanded through veneer" or similar wording you'll find many images showing similar or identical results. Even with older furniture where the veneers could be much thicker than is typical for recent furniture it is risky to use any form of power sander, even paying very close attention to what's going on. Older stuff can still be risky to power sand because it may not be possible to tell if someone has previously sanded the surface, removing some of the thickness already.

@JackA. Your final sentence is, um, completely incorrect. Of course 'latex' house paint hardens. Otherwise walls too would be sticky! While there are potential incompatibility issues with using waterbased wall paints on furniture that still has finish on it, and there are definitely superior choices (in terms of colour depth, durability, range of surface finish), there's no fundamental reason one "can't" or "shouldn't" use wall paint to paint furniture.... which is why it's so incredibly common to do so.

@JackA. Your anecdotal experience, while absolutely of value, does not speak widely enough to the broader picture. There's a huge range of house/wall paints from innumerable makers, with varied formulas. I do want to emphasis again that, yes, there are definitely superior paint choices for the purpose, however one can mitigate or entirely prevent the issue you describe simply by varnishing or lacquering any surfaces that might be subject to long-term tacking problems.

So what I see is that this table was laminated with a thin veneer.  And you sanded right through it.
So I see 3 options for you.

accept it as is and learn from your mistake.  (Never use a sander on veneer)
sand off the rest so it is at lest the same (or make some kind of pattern by sanding)
learn to veneer/repair veneer. (or pay someone to do it which is probably more than just buying another table)
Buy a new table.


100% sanded right through the veneer. Hope it's not a valuable antique!


Paint completely.
Learn to faux paint grain.

